# asp.net mvc outbound routing from a GET form post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I have a route that looks like this:

```
new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "PhotoGallery", slug = "photo-gallery", filtertype = UrlParameter.Optional, filtervalue = UrlParameter.Optional, sku = UrlParameter.Optional}
```

and I have a form that looks like this:

```
  <%using(Html.BeginForm("PhotoGallery", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Get)) {%>
  <%:Html.Hidden("filtertype", "1")%>
  <%:Html.DropDownList("filtervalue", ViewData["Designers"] as SelectList, "Photos by designer", new { onchange = "selectJump(this)" })%>
  <%}%>
```

Right now when the form is submitted I get the form values appended to the url as query strings (?filtertype=1 etc) Is there a way to get this form to use routing to render the URL?

So the form would post a URL that looked like this:

```
www.site.com/photo-gallery/1/selectedvalue
```

and not like"

```
www.site.com/photo-gallery?filtertype=1&filtervalue=selectedvalue
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have some of the parameters present, Mvc will create a Query String type Url unless it finds an exact matching url.

Suggest you will need something like:

```
routes.Add("testRoute", 
new Route("/{action}/{controller}/{slug}/{filtertype}/{filtervalue}",
new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "PhotoGallery", slug = "photo-gallery", filtertype = UrlParameter.Optional, filtervalue = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

make sure this is before your existing route

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ended up using the PRG pattern to get the effect I needed. My routing is to complicated and would not allow for such a general rule.